# Spring Security+MVC annotations Illegal argument exception

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-annotations

I'm using spring MVC and spring security.

I have annotation-driven controller and trying to add security annotations to it.

Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController implements MessageSourceAware {

    @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/somepage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPage(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {
        // logic
        return ADMIN_VIEW_NAME;
    }
```

My `spring-security.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/denied">

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>-->

        <security:form-login
                login-page="/login"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
                default-target-url="/index"/>

        <security:logout
                invalidate-session="true"
                logout-success-url="/login"
                logout-url="/logout"/>

    </security:http>

    <!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="authManager">
            <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- Use a SHA encoder since the user's passwords are stored as SHA in the database -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>

    <!-- A custom service where Spring will retrieve users and their corresponding access levels  -->
    <bean id="authManager" class="some.package.AdminManager"/>

</beans>
```

When I try open secured page I get following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [$Proxy139]
Method [public java.lang.String SomeController.getPage(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)]
Resolved arguments: 
[0] [type=org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper] [value=SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7a31c825]]]
[1] [type=org.springframework.validation.support.BindingAwareModelMap] [value={}]
```

If I remove secured annotation and uncomment following line in `spring-security.xml`:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
```

Everything works fine.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Move

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

from spring-security.xml to the xml file referenced by the main dispatcher servlet, usually something like servlet-context.xml or application-context.xml

See here
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context

Also, I think you need to add ' proxy-target-class="true" ' to the global-method-security annotation as well like

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. `proxy-target-class` is necessary. I've added cglib and asm and it works.